# Spring integration mail poller

Tags: java, spring, imap, spring-integration

I want to configure a poller for my mail adapter, to run just once or run it programmatically.

This is a standalone app `(java -jar xxxx.jar)`, so I think maybe one option is configure the `fixed-rate` attribute, to an arbitrary max value and then exit the application, ie: `System.exit(0)`.

Are there more alternatives or some kind of 'correct approach', for this case?

This is my `integration-context.xml` :

```
<int-mail:inbound-channel-adapter id="imapAdapter"
                                  store-uri="imaps://${imap.user}:${imap.password}@${imap.server.ip}:${imap.server.port}/inbox"
                                  channel="receiveChannel"
                                  auto-startup="true"
                                  should-delete-messages="false"
                                  should-mark-messages-as-read="false"                                      
                                  java-mail-properties="javaMailProperties" 
                                  mail-filter-expression="subject matches '(?i)*UNSUSCRIBE*'">
    <int:poller max-messages-per-poll="1" fixed-rate="5000"/>
</int-mail:inbound-channel-adapter>
```

PS: Unfortunately `imap-idle-channel-adapter` is not an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can suggest to you `OnlyOnceTrigger`:

```
@Bean
public Trigger onlyOnceTrigger() {
       return new Trigger() {
              private final AtomicBoolean invoked = new AtomicBoolean();
              @Override
              public Date nextExecutionTime(TriggerContext triggerContext) {
                    return this.invoked.getAndSet(true) ? null : new Date();
              }
       };
}
```

Which should be injected to your `<int:poller>` of that adapter.

However you should take care about some `barrier` for the entire application if you say that it is standalone one and you really shouldn't lose process before you decide to close the app.

One of those good choice is `CountDownLatch` with `1` count as a bean. You should wait on it from your `main` before `System.exit(0)` or just use the last one in the end of your process:

```
<outbound-channel-adapter expression="T(System).exit(0)"/>
```

However you should think more if it really is suitable for your to run the adapter only once and if that `max-messages-per-poll="1"` is really good option.

There may be no messages in the mail box, so `onlyOnceTrigger` may finish without good result for you and your app has strained into the void...

Comment: Thank you so much!, I managed to use the onlyOnceTrigger. I have another question I'm using DirectChannel to receive msgs. Is the correct channel for the barrier you mentioned above or should I use other? (I'm not able to know when the process is done and therefore do the countDown to Latch) I have something like `receiveChannel.suscribe() ...`

Comment: Actually, it doesn't matter which channel type is after `poller`. From other side sometimes `DirectChannel` is better, because that downstrem process will be done within poller's thread. So you don't start a new one. Anyway for your case `poller` is separete thread and you really should wait result from that thread or just call `System.exit(0)` from the end of process. To answer to your question: no, channel isn't a `barrier`. It is something which should prevent your application to invoke `System.exit(0)` unconditionally.