# Is there a way to manually start an inbound-channel adapter? [Spring integration]

Tags: spring-integration

```
 <int-file:inbound-channel-adapter 
    directory="#{dir}"
    channel="inp" filename-regex="^.*\.(xml|lst)$"  prevent-duplicates="false">
  <int:poller max-messages-per-poll="1" cron ="#{timer}"/>
</int-file:inbound-channel-adapter>
```

Is there a way to start the above inbound-channel-adapter before the poller fires?
Normally the poller fires around once a day but sometimes I need immediate operation based on user's interaction (when user clicks on a 'start' button)

Thanks,

Ferenc

Answer (score 2):

For you info: any `inbound-channel-adapter` can be `started/stopped` manually (you should provide an `id` for that component). But we should understand that it doesn't help us yet. Because any activity is based on the `trigger`.

As I see your requirement to start polling immediately by user event, so you should provide some appropriate `Trigger` implementation. E.g. [`OnlyOnceTrigger`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26306739/spring-integration-mail-poller)

I'd suggests to add one more `<int-file:inbound-channel-adapter>` with the same options and the same `channel`, but with that custom trigger do not break your `cron` logic.
That new `<int-file:inbound-channel-adapter>` should marked with `auto-startup="false"`. The user `start` button just should `start()` that component and, yes, `stop` immediately. The single polling task will be initiated.

Here you should think about some `OnlyOnceTrigger` `reset()` to allow it to start the new polling task on the next button click.

Yes, you even can implement some complex `Trigger` including both `cron` `once` triggering operations to avoid one more `<int-file:inbound-channel-adapter>`, but that will be already up to you.

Comment: How often this nextExecutionTime() method called? 

What would be the situation when my poller only fires once a day?

Imaging the following timeline
:
10:10 - poller fires
10:20 - user clicked on the START button

Do we have to wait for next day 10:10 when system calls nextExecutionTime() to determine the next run's date?

Comment: Unfortunately `Trigger` doesn't do anything itself. All hard work is done in the `TaskScheduler#schedule(Runnable task, Trigger trigger)` implementation. That `TaskScheduler` calculates the next fire date and populates the task to the internal `executor`. The finish of that task initiates the calculation for the next scheduling. So, any custom fires won't impact to those tasks which have been already scheduled. That's why I think you won't be able to implement everything in the single trigger and therefore single `inbound-channel-adapter`